# How to get ID of current element selected by javascript

Tags: javascript, custom-list, list-item

How to get current element of list by javascript. The element clicked by three dots. Please help. From the Sharepoint list called "Stuff".

And after click on three dots i want to get a ID of element. Please help.

Comment: Wrong forum.  This should be asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: But I want to get a eleent from Sharepoint list. Not from javascript solo.

Comment: You might to add more details.  I have updated the tags

Comment: I have got a list called Stuff. And i must get ID of element which was clicked.  By three dot's. How could I atchieve this ? Please help.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: The duplicate Is because i can't find solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()` method to get the items ID.

The code would be as below:

```
var selectedItem = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems()[0].id;
```

[image]

Comment: hi @GrzegorzZ, did you check the above code ? is it working for you ?

Comment: Yes I checked, but this don't work at my solution. I don't know where should I write this.

Comment: Can You give sample of code ? Please help.

Comment: If I put thisYour code the javascript code stoping work.